# How to extract text from this specific page ? Unable to do so with bs4+python

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, text-parsing

I have the following page:

http://greyhoundbet.racingpost.com/#card/race_id=1632746&r_date=2018-08-17&tab=form

It contains a series of information organized in "tables". I need to "extract" that information (rows and columns) to manipulate the info later.

Knowing that I'm a newbie, i tried to do it with bs4 with python but I wasn't successful. What would you recomend ?

**1) Should I use a program language that would allow me to read the text from the page (which one should I use ? what sould I look for?) and then manipulate it ?**

**2) Can I get the text manually (ctrl+c) and send it to python somehow ?**

---

How would you get the info from the page in the easiest way to later work with the data ?

Thank you all and I'm sorry if this is a dumb question. I've been struggling with that for the past week.

Regards,
P.

EDIT:
I was thinking in use an object oriented approach to separate every greyhound and to study each number. Maybe its better to do it in C# ?

Comment: For parsing you have to use selenium because all data are loaded from javascript

Comment: Thanks, utks009. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would suggest either Selenium with Python bindings https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/, or CasperJS (http://casperjs.org/) which is based on phantomjs. The second is written in Javascript.
2. Create a text file and paste the copied text. Then read the file with python :

   with open('page_text.txt') as f:
       lines = f.readlines()

You cannot scrape the page with bs4. You need a 'headless browser', a tool that can load dynamic webpages (like Selenium etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this repeatedly, then you should probably go for a headless (drive-able) browser, as other answers suggest.

However, if you don't need to do it that often, you may be able to get the info from your normal browser. E.g., in Firefox:

```
Right Click -> Select All
Right Click -> View Selection Source
File -> Save Page As...
```

This gives you a serialization of the current DOM (as constructed dynamically by JavaScript), as opposed to the original fetched document.